# How to get all child records by condition in one table

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table:

```
public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public Category Categories { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to get all child records by field "Code". For example, by category code "C1" I want to get child records: "C2" and "C4".

```
ID  ParentID    Code    Name
1   null        C1      C1
2   1           C2      C2
3   1           C4      C4
4   null        C3      C3
```

How I can do this using LINQ?

Comment: Is it possible for "C2" and "C4" to have children of their own and should they be included in the results?

Comment: Yes, they can have childrens. But I need only 1 level, without children child nodes

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I use Postgres.

Comment: In this case if hierarchy can be quite nested I woulduse an [recursive query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html) not a LINQ. Or maybe create a view and use it to query.

Comment: Are you searching for a specific code? Just group by ParentId

`data.GroupBy(x => x.ParentId).Where(x => x.Key == 1);`

Answer (score 0):

```
// get the parent ID
var parentID = repo.Categories.Where(x => x.Code == "C1").FirstOrDefault().ID;
if (parentID != 0) {
    // find by parent ID
    var subCategories = repo.Categories.Where(x => x.ParentID == parentID);
}
```

to do this in one query, using EntityFramework, you should define ParentCategory as a foreign key entity in Category like this:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public Category Categories { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

otherwise, you can use a Join: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-joining-operator-join

Comment: Can it be one LINQ query?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a learning question so I will not give a full answer. However:

1. You can try a join operator linking the ID of the parent object and the `ParentID` of the child object. You should be able to do this in a single query.
2. It might be easier to do 2 queries. The first query selects the parent ID(s) and the second selects the child objects:

   ```
    var parentQuery = from parent in categories
                      // conditions here
                      select.parent.ID;

    var childQuery = from parentId in parentQuery
                     from child in categories
                     // conditions here
                     select child;
   ```

As @GuruStron said, this will traverse one level of a tree so tree-walking through a database will require a different solution.